# os.path.join with str subclass

Tags: python, string, path, python-3.x

Does anybody knows why the `os.path.join` function doesn't work with subclasses of `str`?

(I'm using Python3.2 x64 and Python2.7 x86 on Windows and the result is the same)

That's the code I have

```
class Path(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Path(os.path.join(self, other))

p = Path(r'C:\the\path')
d = p + 'some_file.txt'
```

and the result I want:

```
'C:\\the\\path\\some_file.txt'
```

but the output is `\\some_file.txt` no matter the value of `self`.

I know I can do either `str(self)` or store it as `self.path` and use later, but why does `os.join.path` doesn't accept a str subclass nor raise an error (like when you use a number or any non string type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, check out the source (Python32\Lib\ntpath.py).  Relevant bits:

"""Join two or more pathname components, inserting "\" as needed.  **If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components will be discarded.**""" (emphasis added)

Towards the bottom of the function `join` is attempting to place a `\` between the two pieces using `path += '\\' + b` (where `b` is `some_file.txt`) -- which first adds `\` and `some_file.txt` (which are plain strings), then adds that to `Path(r'c:\the\path')` by calling `Path.__add__(r'c:\the\path', r'\some_file.txt')`, which will *again* call `os.path.join`...

Did you notice the leading `\` now on the filename?  That is why the initial part of the path is getting lost.

Calling `os.path.join` with `str(self)` (or `self.path`) works because then `os.path.join` is only being called once instead of twice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `os.path.join` uses the build in `__add__` method, this can be verified by putting a print statement in the `__add__` method.

```
>>> class Path(str):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...             print 'add'
...             return Path(os.path.join(str(self), other))
... 
>>> p = Path(r'/the/path')
>>> p + 'thefile.txt'
add
>>> class Path(str):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...             print 'add'
...             return Path(os.path.join(self, other))
... 
>>> p = Path(r'/the/path')
>>> p + 'file.txt'
add
add
# add printed twice
```

Simplest solution:
Change

```
return Path(os.path.join(self, other))
```

to

```
return Path(os.path.join(str(self), other))
```

It works.

Comment: Well, that's what I just wrote in my question... I wanted to know if it's a bug or CPython implementation or something else. BTW `isinstance` will return True in this case

Comment: Yeah you're right. It must have `string.__class__.__name__ == 'str'`

Comment: No, the interpreter wouldn't check that string because I can change it any time...

Comment: Ok, last theory. The built in __add__ is used by os.path.join. Updated my answer with that info

Comment: Yes, that's it. It makes a lot of sense now :)

Comment: Agreed. There must be a safeguard

Comment: The safeguard is that `os.path.join` is using `+=` to concatenate the path pieces together -- if that is changed to `+` infinite recursion occurs.